# sudo -u <current_user> -H gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/file

Tags: 18.04, gnome, sudo, dbus, gsettings

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
The above command (and other gsetting command when used with `sudo -u <user_name> -H`) is/are showing a weird behavior..  (I'm expecting it to set the gsetting of the current user)

- Firstly, after using the above command from terminal/script, if we try `gsettings get` the desktop background, it'll show as the picture we set it to previously, but the desktop background is not changed.
- Second part is, if we log off and log-in (or even, open the background seiings in the settings UI and close it without making any changes) the `gsettings get` will now display back the normal value, i,e. the current display picture(not the set by us)

Please help me understand this behavior, and what can I do to make it set the gsettings to the current user (using sudo).
Please refer: [Trouble with handling sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193164/trouble-with-handling-sudo)
Thanks a loads!

---

**Edit 1:**
Just figured out this is happening coz of missing an env variable DBUS_SESSION_DBUS_ADDRESS. When we are using `sudo -Hu <user> env > text.txt` we get a very limited subset of env varables.. in which the above variable is missing..  From: [Background not changing using gsettings from cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742870/background-not-changing-using-gsettings-from-cron/743024#743024)

Now, my question boils down to how to add that env variable while I'm setting gsettings through python script! **OR** is there any other better way of doing it?

Comment: run `sudo -Hu <current_user> env > test.txt`, you'll see many environment settings are missing.  I guess it's related.

Comment: Why do you need `sudo` to run the command for the *current user*? Am I missing something?

Comment: @pomsky , I understand that things will get easy without sudo..  
But, it is a part of flow of scripts, certain set of scripts provides what changes to make in gsettings and at the end of the flow, I'll have to apply the changes to the system... the previous scripts need _sudo_ and I want the applying to gsettings part to go with the flow

Comment: @AlvinLiang , yeah.. just figured out this is happening coz of missing an env variable DBUS_SESSION_DBUS_ADDRESS..